# Using JavaScript, how can you tell if a user is tabbing backwards?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, accessibility

I've got an HTML link, and I want to take some action when the user tabs away from it - but only if the user is tabbing forwards through the document, as opposed to backwards.

Is there a reliable cross-browser way to detect which way the user is tabbing through the document, or indeed if they're tabbing through the document at all? I'm binding to the `blur` event, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the user is tabbing.

I've had a look at inspecting the value of `document.activeElement`, or the `hasFocus` attribute of the previous focusable element in the source, but:

1. those seem like relatively recent additions, and thus might not be widely supported, and
2. I'm not sure they'll be inspectable when the `blur` event fires, as even if the user is tabbing, I don't think the next element will be focused yet.

Comment: It's very peculiar of you to ask such questions since your reputation is rather high and especially because you have **Javascript**, **HTML** and **jQuery** badges... I'm a bit baffled. :S

Comment: What do you want to do in response to it? There's a general accessibility guideline that you should never 'change context' (eg. move focus elsewhere, navigate to a different page) in response to focus change - regardless of direction. The right thing to do here may depend on what you plan on doing in response to the focus change...

Comment: @BrendanMcK: sure — I’ve since decided to avoid such detailed fiddling with the user’s keyboard actions. I think the whole thing was ill-conceived.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to handle `keydown` event on the link itself.

```
$("your link selector").keydown(function(evt){
    if (evt.which === 9)
    {
        if(evt.shiftKey === true)
        {
            // user is tabbing backward
        }
        else
        {
            // User is tabbing forward
        }
    }
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ8wD/1) that detects forward and backward tabbing on a particular link.

> **Sidenote**: You didn't specify jQuery tag on your question al though I provided jQuery code in my answer. Since you hold Javascript as well as jQuery badges I suppose it's going to be trivial for you to convert my code to pure Javascript.

Comment: @Robert: sure, I was thinking about that, but I wasn’t sure if detecting the shift key was a bit brittle. a) Is detecting the shift key reliable cross-browser? b) Is shift-tab always the way users tab backwards through the document? The answer to those two questions may well be yes, but I thought I should ask to see if anyone had a better idea than I do.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: It won’t work on touch devices. But for most cases Robert’s solution is very good.

Comment: @Robert: great answer btw, I'll run your example through a few browsers and report any lurking incompatibilities.

Comment: @Paul: Thank you and yes do that. It will provide additional information for future reference.

Comment: Be sure to check with Opera: it has a rather interesting keyboard model: TAB only moves between certain types of input fields (text areas, buttons, etc), not links; to navigate between links, you use SHIFT+ arrow keys. There's no concept of forwards or backwards here, it's purely directional.

Comment: @Brendan: Now that's stupidity. They're trying to invent water that has been flowing for a long time. **Shift + arrow keys** have always been related to text selection.

Comment: @Robert - I'm very much inclined to agree with your there - additionally, directional navigation is not very useful if you can't *see* what direction you need to navigate in (unlike linear tab, which will get to everything eventually). But that's how it is - worth being aware of either way.

Comment: @Brendan: You're right. We have to be aware of it even though we don't necessarily agree with it. But we don't have a choice now do we?

Comment: @Robert: I think perhaps the thing to do is to at least make sure that whatever you do for the 'normal' browser case doesn't end up horribly messed up on Opera, and can still be used - even if not used elegantly - ie. have whatever the solution is degrade (somewhat) gracefully in that case.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: jQuery normalizes the event variable, use `evt.which` instead of `evt.keyCode` for a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a good solution from Robert, maybe you can leverage [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) attribute? Set it for your html links and other “tabbable” items. Then check it in javascript.

Solution with tabindex: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KK8Ew/3/)

> **Side effect**: Elements will also react on mouse clicks. They will behave correctly. So this might be a good side effect or bad side effect depending on your needs.